# How do I change the action for Force Click on a Force Touch trackpad?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have a new MacBook Pro Retina 13 Early 2015 with the [Force Touch trackpad](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/features-retina/#force-click).

It's described to have the following feature:

> Click and continue to press on the trackpad to enable new capabilities, like looking up a word's definition, previewing a file in the Finder, or creating a new Calendar event when you Force click a date in the text of an email.

Generally: **How can I change, tweak, tune, enhance the 'capability' of this force click?**

Particularly: I'd love to have it do translation in Safari and Terminal much more frequently than I want it to do dictionary lookup.

Comment: Are there any plist values that can be changed that drive this behavior in the background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this tool called BetterTouchTool
https://folivora.ai/downloads

> BetterTouchTool is a great, feature packed app that allows you to
> configure many gestures for your Magic Mouse, Macbook Trackpad and
> Magic Trackpad and also Mouse Gestures for normal mice. It also allows
> you to configure actions for keyboard shortcuts, normal mice buttons
> and the Apple Remote. In addition to this it has an iOS companion App
> (BTT Remote) which can also be configured to control your Mac the way
> you want.

It allows me to set a HUGE variety of actions for TONS of mouse gestures.

I am able to create actions for FORCE click on specific areas of the trackpad, and even multifinger force click.  It is exactly what I've been looking for.

It is extremely useful.

[removed link to old versions at http://www.boastr.net/]

Comment: You cannot configure single finger force click though. Only 2 or more.

Comment: The Software is no longer maintained.

Comment: Modern versions of BetterTouchTool are available at: https://folivora.ai/downloads

Answer (score 8):

If you want translations instead of dictionary lookups, you can change the preferences in the dictionary application. In the preferences you can decide what the dictionary checks when you force click a word. For example, you can uncheck the dictionary lookups and check the french to english dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Such a fail for what could be a feature rich action trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Apples has not released an option to change parameters of the Force Click feature quite yet. It's Apple after all, when they feel it's ready they will add the granularity you are seeking.

These are the options currently available to according to [Apple's published documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352):

These are the Force Click options available at this time.

1. Rename any label
2. Preview any file
3. Preview Calendar dates
4. Click on any date to create an event
5. Drop a pin in Maps
6. Pressure sensitive zoom in Maps
7. Lookup the definition of any word
8. Pressure sensitive fast forward
9. Show all windows from an open app
10. Right click on certain dock icons
11. Edit contact details
12. Add a contact with number or email address
13. Preview any link (Safari only)
14. Show Do Not Disturb options in Messages
15. Pressure sensitive drawing

Comment: This only allows me to "adjust the pressure you need to Force click your trackpad", it doesn't indicate in any way how to "change, tweak, tune, enhance the 'capability' of Force Click".

Comment: You appear to be fairly competent, given your askdiff score, you must be aware that they may not have released an option to change parameters of the Force Click feature quite yet. It's Apple after all, when they feel it's ready they will add the granularity you are seeking.

Comment: These are the Force Click options available at this time.1.Rename any label 2.Preview any file 3.Preview Calendar dates 4.Click on any date to create an event 5.Drop a pin in Maps 6.Pressure sensitive zoom in Maps 7.Lookup the definition of any word 8.Pressure sensitive fast forward 9.Show all windows from an open app 10.Right click on certain dock icons 11.Edit contact details 12.Add a contact with number or email address 13.Preview any link (Safari only) 14.Show Do Not Disturb options in Messages 15.Pressure sensitive drawing

Comment: A down vote is used to communicate the quality of the answer.  "Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information." http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote  A snarky comment like "Google is your friend", as part of an answer that doesn't specifically answer the question asked, isn't welcome.
Try merging your comment about the available options and no tweaks yet.