# MacBook force click as secondary click

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

Is there a way I can use the force click on my MacBook trackpad as a right click (secondary click)?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can't override a single finger force click, since that [always produces a left click action](https://www.reddit.com/r/BetterTouchTool/comments/3clmg0/force_touch_for_one_finger/).
Using two fingers, you may as well use the standard two finger tap/click for secondary click.

Answer (score -1):

The [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/), as mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219158/45492), cannot replace the force click per se, but offers you some alternatives, such as "2 finger force click".

[image: BTT]